# Google errorprone java compiler - Default bugpatterns? Mark ignore?

Tags: java, guava, errorprone

I am getting some warnings regarding the accessing static method from a variable over class.

Is there a way to tell errorprone to ignore these warnings? Is error-prone loaded with a set of "bugpatterns"? Is it all of these:

https://github.com/google/error-prone/tree/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/errorprone/bugpatterns

**How can I override for instance this to stop complaining:**

> Warning:(111, 21) java: [StaticAccessedFromInstance] Static method
>   info should not be accessed from an object instance; instead use
>   Log.info (see errorprone.info/bugpattern/StaticAccessedFromInstance)
>   Did you mean 'Log.info( EntityError.class, Gson.asString(this) );'?

I am using Intellij.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [errorprone flags documentation](http://errorprone.info/docs/flags), you can switch the check off with:

```
-Xep:StaticAccessedFromInstance:OFF
```

However, I agree with Kayaman: you are better off fixing the problem than working to ignore it.

Comment: Btw, this options would be nice if could be configured through maven, so it's a setting that is persisted.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am mistaken; but I think that "eclipse code cleanup" is able to fix this kind of code problem automatically.

My suggestion would be to rather spend time to understand how such bugs can be easily fixed; versus spending time to suppress the corresponding warning.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using Intellij. Note that this error is relevant to errorprone compiler. Suprressing everywhere or globally?

Comment: @momo IntelliJ is more than capable of doing that as well I'm sure. Fix the problem instead of hiding it.

Comment: I don't want to fix the problem, that's what the question is about. Ignoring it, preferably without using a local (or global) editor. I am asking on how to do this with errorprone. Ignoring certain built in warnings.